# Flutter can't build App on Android because it can't find required tool in JDK installation

Tags: linux, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-sdk-2.3

I can build Apps with flutter for Linux device but i can't for any connected device.
When i run `flutter doctor` i get

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.277, on Linux, locale en_NG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

But i have Android Studio Installed
The thing is i don't even use Android Studio, I use Visual Studio Code but i had it Installed because of some other issue.

The problem now is
whenever i try to build an App on My Android, which i have connected:

```
$ flutter devices
2 connected devices:

SM A505F (mobile) • RZ8M902VAZK • android-arm64 • Android 10 (API 29)
Linux (desktop)   • linux       • linux-x64     • Linux
```

i get the error

```
$ flutter run -d RZ8M902VAZK
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A505F in debug mode...
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.                    
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 8s                                                      
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         9.5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

but i have JDK installed:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~18.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)
```

Many  Thanks!!

Comment: whats the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/` ?

Comment: ```ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION  docs     jre  man    THIRD_PARTY_README
bin      include  lib  src.zip
```

Comment: and what is under `bin`? `java  jfr  jjs  keytool  pack200  rmid  rmiregistry  unpack200
`?

Comment: ```appletviewer  javac     jdeps jsadebugd     policytool   unpack200
clhsdb       javadoc     jfr  jstack       rmic    wsgen
extcheck      javah     jhat jstat       rmid    wsimport
hsdb       javap     jinfo jstatd       rmiregistry  xjc
idlj       java-rmi.cgi  jjs  keytool       schemagen
jar       jcmd     jmap native2ascii  serialver
jarsigner     jconsole     jps  orbd       servertool
java       jdb     jrunscript pack200       tnameserv
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you just need to map the JDK built-in with Android Studio. Map the JDK path below using the terminal.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/"Android Studio.app"/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
```